# Google Places AutoComplete Not Displaying Results

Tags: flutter, dart, google-places-api

I've been having a lot of problems trying to get my googleplaces autocomplete api to properly function. When I reboot my app, it works for the first search, then it never provides any search results after. The autocomplete simply does not function, it never displays any prediction that a user may click. I have followed various tutorials online about how to fix this problem but I am simply not sure what is causing it. My api is enabled, so it can't be that. Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:georeminder/services/notification_plugin.dart';
import 'package:georeminder/utilities/size_config.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:georeminder/services/named_notification.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';
import 'package:georeminder/screens/reminders_screen.dart';

const googleApiKey = "APIKEY";
GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: googleApiKey);
List<NamedNotification> notifications = [];
List<NotificationPlugin> notificationPlugins = [];
int id = 0;
Position currentPosition;
var placeId, address;
double lat, lng;

class NewReminderScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewReminderScreenState createState() => _NewReminderScreenState();
}

class _NewReminderScreenState extends State<NewReminderScreen> {

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getCurrentLocation();
  }

  static String title;
  static String description;
  static DateTime _dateTime;

  int sharedValue = 0;

  final Map<int, Widget> dateTimePlace = const <int, Widget>{
    0: Text('Time'),
    1: Text('Place'),
  };

  String convertDate(DateTime date) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("EEEE, LLL d, yyyy, h:mm a");
    String string = dateFormat.format(date);
    return string;
  }

  getCurrentLocation(){
    final Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager;
    geolocator
      .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
      .then((Position position){
        setState(() {
          currentPosition = position;
        });
      }).catchError((e){
        print(e);
      });
  }

  void apiError(){
    print('There was an error dawg');
  }

  double _kPickerSheetHeight = SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 20;
  Widget _buildBottomPicker(Widget picker) {
    return Container(
      height: _kPickerSheetHeight,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
      color: CupertinoColors.white,
      child: DefaultTextStyle(
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: CupertinoColors.black,
          fontSize: 22.0,
        ),
        child: GestureDetector(
          // Blocks taps from propagating to the modal sheet and popping.
          onTap: () {},
          child: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            child: picker,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail = await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);
      placeId = p.placeId;
      lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;
      address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);
    }
  }

  Widget iosbuildPage(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0: // If User picks a Time Reminder
        return Container(
          height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 100,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                // Space from top
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5,
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              ),
              Container(
                // New title
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Title',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                // Title TextField
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                child: TextField(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    title = value;
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff212121),
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    hintText: 'Enter a title for your reminder',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(
                          15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                // Space Between TextFields
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5,
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              ),
              Container(
                // New Description title
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Description',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                // Description TextField
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: null,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    description = value;
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff212121),
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    hintText: 'Enter a description for your reminder',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(
                          15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                // Space Between TextFields
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5,
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              ),
              AutoSizeText(
                // Represents the selected date
                _dateTime == null
                    ? 'No time has been picked'
                    : convertDate(_dateTime),
                maxLines: 1,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                // Space Between TextFields
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2,
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                // Button that allows you to access the CupertinoDatePicker
                child: Text(
                  'Select a Time',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                color: Color(0xff424242),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(
                      15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  showCupertinoModalPopup(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return _buildBottomPicker(
                          CupertinoDatePicker(
                            mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
                            onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime date) {
                              setState(() {
                                _dateTime = date;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                // Space Between TextFields
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 15,
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              ),
              Container(
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 90,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Create Reminder',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  color: Color(0xffff3f80),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(
                        15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      NotificationPlugin newNotification = NotificationPlugin();
                      newNotification.showAtDayAndTimeNotification(_dateTime, id, title, description);
                      notificationPlugins.add(newNotification);
                      NamedNotification listNotification = NamedNotification(_dateTime, id, title, description, true);
                      notifications.add(listNotification);
                      id = id + 1;
                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
        break;
      case 1: // If User picks a Place Reminder
        return Container(
          height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 100,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                // Space from top
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5,
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              ),
              Container(
                // New title title
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Title',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                // Title TextField
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                child: TextField(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    title = value;
                    // print(title);
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff212121),
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    hintText: 'Enter a title for your reminder',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(
                          15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                // Space Between TextFields
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5,
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              ),
              Container(
                // New Description title
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 5),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Description',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                // Description TextField
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: null,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    description = value;
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff212121),
                  ),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    hintText: 'Enter a description for your reminder',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(
                          15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                // Space Between TextFields
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 5,
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              ),
              AutoSizeText(
                'The address should appear here',
                maxLines: 1,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                // Space Between TextFields
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2,
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              ),
              Container(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Select a Place',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  color: Color(0xff424242),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(
                        15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Prediction prediction = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                        context: context, 
                        apiKey: googleApiKey,
                        //
                        location: Location(currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude),
                        radius: 100000000,
                        mode: Mode.overlay,
                        language: "en",
                    );
                    displayPrediction(prediction);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                // Space Between TextFields
                height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 15,
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 100,
              ),
              Container(
                width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 90,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Create Reminder',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  color: Color(0xffff3f80),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(
                        15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {

                    });
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
    }
    return Container();
  }


  Widget platformScaffoldNewReminder(BuildContext context) {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff212121),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xff212121),
                largeTitle: Text(
                  'New Reminder',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                middle: SizedBox(
                  width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 45,
                  child: CupertinoSegmentedControl<int>(
                    borderColor: Colors.white,
                    unselectedColor: Color(0xff212121),
                    selectedColor: Colors.white,
                    children: dateTimePlace,
                    onValueChanged: (int val) {
                      setState(() {
                        sharedValue = val;
                      });
                    },
                    groupValue: sharedValue,
                  ),
                ),
                trailing: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  [
                    iosbuildPage(sharedValue),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff212121),
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                text: 'Time',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Place',
              ),
            ],
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          title: Text('New Reminder'),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff212121),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            androidbuildPage(0),
            androidbuildPage(1),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return platformScaffoldNewReminder(context);
    }
  }
```

I truly would appreciate any help as I have been stuck for a week trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you confirm, you have enabled Billing for your project on Google API console?
It is compulsory now

Comment: I have not enabled billing. I will enable it now and update you on whether it works.

Comment: You can check the references here: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start

Comment: I updated my billing info and it has worked. Thank you for your help. I was wondering if you could explain how billing works? Like, if I search something to test my app, does it automatically charge my account?

Comment: Pricings are explained here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing

Answer (score 1):

First enable billing on Google console.

If it persist then add `type: []`
Then increase `radius: 100000000`

Billing is more important

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
  ...
</body>

javascript 

function initialize() {
  var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)


You can see an example at http://www.redwoodtransit.org.
```

Comment: Could I possibly have a bit of context regarding your answer?

Comment: Sensor is an obsolete parameter in the script tag.